# Java: How to solve Readers-Writer Problem?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, synchronization

I want to implement a solution for Readers-Writer problem. The main rule is, only one writer can write at a time and no other writer or reader can write or read, but if a writer doesn't write , multiple readers can read. In the main class, I tried to run threads with `executorService.execute` but i had some problems i guess. I don't know much about `executorService`. The program never ends and I guess there is some output problems.

My code is below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;


public class ReaderWriter {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ReadWriteLock RW = new ReadWriteLock();


    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));

    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
 }
}


class ReadWriteLock{
    static Semaphore readLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static Semaphore writeLock = new Semaphore(1);
    volatile static int readCount = 0;

    public void readLock() throws InterruptedException {

        readLock.acquire();
        readCount++;
        if (readCount == 1) {
            writeLock.acquire();
        }
        readLock.release();

        //Reading section
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is READING");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has FINISHED READING");

        //Releasing section
        readLock.acquire();
        readCount--;
        if(readCount == 0) {
            writeLock.release();
        }
        readLock.release();
    }
    public void writeLock() throws InterruptedException {
        writeLock.acquire();
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        writeLock.release();
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
    }
}




class Writer implements Runnable
{
    private ReadWriteLock RW_lock;


    public Writer(ReadWriteLock rw) {
        RW_lock = rw;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true){
            try {
                RW_lock.writeLock();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}



class Reader implements Runnable
{
    private ReadWriteLock RW_lock;


    public Reader(ReadWriteLock rw) {
        RW_lock = rw;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            try {
                RW_lock.readLock();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

And the output is not right i think for this problem:

```
Thread pool-1-thread-1 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-2 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-1 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-2 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-3 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-3 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-4 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-4 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-8 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-7 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-6 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-8 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-8 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-6 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-6 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-7 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-7 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-8 has FINISHED READING
```

In this output there is 2 writers writing at the same time.

**OUTPUT EDIT:**

```
Thread pool-1-thread-1 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-1 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-1 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-1 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-4 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-4 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-3 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-3 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-2 is WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-2 has finished WRITING
Thread pool-1-thread-8 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-7 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-6 is READING
Thread pool-1-thread-8 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-7 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-5 has FINISHED READING
Thread pool-1-thread-6 has FINISHED READING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The program never ends and i guess there is some output problems.

Add a *flag* into the `ReadWriteLock` class to signals the `Threads` when they should stop working:

```
private final AtomicBoolean keep_working = new AtomicBoolean(true);
```

add a method in the `ReadWriteLock` class to signal the threads to stop:

```
public void stopThreads(){
    keep_working.set(false);
}
```

and add the method to query the *flag*:

```
public boolean keepWorking(){
    return keep_working.get();
}
```

adapt the `Writer` and `Reader` `run` methods, accordingly:

```
 public void run() {
        while (RW_lock.keepWorking()){
           ...
        }
    }
```

on the *main* class add a call to the methods `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()`, `ReadWriteLock.stopThreads`,  and `ExecutorService.shutdown()`:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ReadWriteLock RW = new ReadWriteLock();

    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));

    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { // ...} 
    RW.stopThreads();
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

> And the output is not right i think for this problem:
> (...)
> In this output there is 2 writers writing at the same time.

That is because in :

```
public void writeLock() throws InterruptedException {
    writeLock.acquire();
    System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    writeLock.release();
    System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
}
```

you release the lock before printing *"has finished WRITING"* therefore, a thread waiting for that lock to be released enters and prints "is WRITING" before the first thread has time to print *"has finished WRITING"*. So you need to change the code to:

```
   public void writeLock() throws InterruptedException {
        writeLock.acquire();
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
        writeLock.release();
    }
```

> The main rule is, only one writer can write at a time and no other
> writer or reader can write or read, but if a writer doesn't write ,
> multiple readers can read.

Actually, you can take advantage of the Java [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) Interface.

> **A ReadWriteLock maintains a pair of associated locks, one for
> read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held
> simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no
> writers.** The write lock is exclusive. All ReadWriteLock
> implementations must guarantee that the memory synchronization effects
> of writeLock operations (as specified in the Lock interface) also hold
> with respect to the associated readLock. That is, a thread
> successfully acquiring the read lock will see all updates made upon
> previous release of the write lock.
>
> A read-write lock allows for a greater level of concurrency in
> accessing shared data than that permitted by a mutual exclusion lock.
> It exploits the fact that while only a single thread at a time (a
> writer thread) can modify the shared data, in many cases any number of
> threads can concurrently read the data (hence reader threads). In
> theory, the increase in concurrency permitted by the use of a
> read-write lock will lead to performance improvements over the use of
> a mutual exclusion lock. In practice this increase in concurrency will
> only be fully realized on a multi-processor, and then only if the
> access patterns for the shared data are suitable.

By using that interface you could simplify significantly the `readLock` and `writeLock` methods, to something as follows:

```
   public void readLock() throws InterruptedException {
        shared_resource.readLock().lock();
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is READING");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has FINISHED READING");
        shared_resource.readLock().unlock();
    }
    public void writeLock() throws InterruptedException {
        shared_resource.writeLock().lock();
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
        shared_resource.writeLock().unlock();
    }
```

To complete, you should add a variable that counts the number of writes and reads. So that if there is nothing written, the *read* threads should wait, and in the meantime, the *write* thread should write something, and so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the shutdown or shutdownAndAwaitTermination method of the ExecutorService in the main method.